# Link pointing to different pages

Tags: css, href

I have the following coding:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .clsLink {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1300px;
    }
</style>

<a href="http://www.somewhere.com" class="clsLink"></a>
```

I need the link to point to a different page according to the place where the user clicks in the page.

The link will be divided in three zones:

- Left zone:  calc((100% - 960px)/2)
- Middle zone:  960px
- Right zone:  calc((100% - 960px)/2)

  How could I proceed with this issue?

Comment: make it as three link tags <a> , and just but them side to side so it shows as one link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

three link tags  side to side so it shows as one link,, try this :

html:

```
<a href="http://www.somewhere1.com" class="clsLink">please</a>
<a href="http://www.somewhere2.com" class="clsLink">click</a>
<a href="http://www.somewhere3.com" class="clsLink">here</a>
```

css:

```
 .clsLink {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1300px;
    text-decoration: none;
 }
```